# ABP AppService for hierarchical data

Tags: hierarchical-data, aspnetboilerplate, devextreme

I need an AppService to load a treeview with a recursive collection of entities like these:

```
===Products===
Id
Description
Price
Products[] ====> Id
                 Description
                 Price
                 Products[]

           ====> Id
                 Description
                 Price
                 Products[] ====> Id
                                  Description
                                  Price
                                  Products[]
```

Is there a ready-made class to derive from? If not, could you suggest what class to derive or what interface to implement, and how to proceed, please?

**PS:** Possibly with full CRUD operations, but the most important is understand how to load the data.

Comment: you have to search for `Inclue()` method on internet

Comment: i've tried `Repository.GetAllIncluding(x=>x.Products).ToList()` but this takes all the records at the first level as well (at the root level). Does i need to add a field and filter only the root entities?

Comment: You have to use `GetAllIncluding` at another level also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_productRepository
    .GetAllIncluding(x=>x.Products)
    .Where(p => p.Id == 1); // or whatever condition
    .ToList()

this will give you the list of products and child products of the product with Id 1.

Comment: so i need to identify (adding a field, eg: "mainparent") the root/main parents elements, so i can filter them? is up to me doing this...
`_productRepository .GetAllIncluding(x=>x.Products) .Where(p => p.mainparent == true);`

Comment: there's no built-in for this. actually it's very simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Include` method to specify related data to be included in query results.

Please refer [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data).

You can refer the below sample.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Linq;

namespace EFQuerying.RelatedData
{
    public class Sample
    {
        public static void Run()
        {
            #region SingleInclude
            using (var context = new BloggingContext())
            {
                var blogs = context.Blogs
                    .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
                    .ToList();
            }
            #endregion

            #region IgnoredInclude
            using (var context = new BloggingContext())
            {
                var blogs = context.Blogs
                    .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
                    .Select(blog => new
                    {
                        Id = blog.BlogId,
                        Url = blog.Url
                    })
                    .ToList();
            }
            #endregion

            #region MultipleIncludes
            using (var context = new BloggingContext())
            {
                var blogs = context.Blogs
                    .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
                    .Include(blog => blog.Owner)
                    .ToList();
            }
            #endregion

            #region SingleThenInclude
            using (var context = new BloggingContext())
            {
                var blogs = context.Blogs
                    .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
                        .ThenInclude(post => post.Author)
                    .ToList();
            }
            #endregion

            #region MultipleThenIncludes
            using (var context = new BloggingContext())
            {
                var blogs = context.Blogs
                    .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
                        .ThenInclude(post => post.Author)
                            .ThenInclude(author => author.Photo)
                    .ToList();
            }
            #endregion

            #region MultipleLeafIncludes
            using (var context = new BloggingContext())
            {
                var blogs = context.Blogs
                    .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
                        .ThenInclude(post => post.Author)
                    .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
                        .ThenInclude(post => post.Tags)
                    .ToList();
            }
            #endregion

            #region IncludeTree
            using (var context = new BloggingContext())
            {
                var blogs = context.Blogs
                    .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
                        .ThenInclude(post => post.Author)
                        .ThenInclude(author => author.Photo)
                    .Include(blog => blog.Owner)
                        .ThenInclude(owner => owner.Photo)
                    .ToList();
            }
            #endregion

            #region Eager
            using (var context = new BloggingContext())
            {
                var blog = context.Blogs
                    .Single(b => b.BlogId == 1);

                context.Entry(blog)
                    .Collection(b => b.Posts)
                    .Load();

                context.Entry(blog)
                    .Reference(b => b.Owner)
                    .Load();
            }
            #endregion

            #region NavQueryAggregate
            using (var context = new BloggingContext())
            {
                var blog = context.Blogs
                    .Single(b => b.BlogId == 1);

                var postCount = context.Entry(blog)
                    .Collection(b => b.Posts)
                    .Query()
                    .Count();
            }
            #endregion

            #region NavQueryFiltered
            using (var context = new BloggingContext())
            {
                var blog = context.Blogs
                    .Single(b => b.BlogId == 1);

                var goodPosts = context.Entry(blog)
                    .Collection(b => b.Posts)
                    .Query()
                    .Where(p => p.Rating > 3)
                    .ToList();
            }
            #endregion
        }
    }
}
```